# preventing Sql injection for a raw condition in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent sql injection for the below where condition. It's receiving data through a search input :

```
$searchValues = preg_split('/\s+/', $query, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);


  ->where(function ($q) use ($searchValues) {
                      foreach ($searchValues as $value) {
                        $q->orWhere(DB::raw("g.title"), 'LIKE', "%{$value}%");
                        $q->orWhere(DB::raw("s.step"), 'LIKE', "%{$value}%");
                      }
                    })
```

I'm new to this, so any guides would be helpful.

Comment: That is how you prevent SQL injection. Your queries are safe. You'd only need to worry if you were attempting to do `DB::raw('g.title LIKE "%{$value}%"')`, which is not safe. By the way, you shouldn't need to pass those column names in via DB::raw. The where will parse the table alias/column names correctly.

Comment: I don't know about laravel, and how the `orWhere` works, but you have to make sure of what it really does. If nothing special is done : just an easy way to concatenate strings,  a value like this : `whatever% OR g.title LIKE '%'  OR g.title LIKE %somethingelse` could inhibit your `g.title` constraint and could lead to the following where clause : `WHERE g.title LIKE %whatever% OR g.title LIKE '%'  OR g.title LIKE %somethingelse%`

Comment: @aynber, Thanks for the clarification. But when I try ( or 1="1) , I can see data returned.

Comment: When you try that for the value?  You might want to double-check what data is being returned. `orWhere` passes the third (or second if the comparison operator is dropped) as a secure parameter. You're only using DB::raw on the column name, so that does not come into play

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is here : [https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#introduction](http://Your%20answer%20is%20here%20:%20https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#introduction).
As your column name is hardcoded and not coming from a user input : it is safe against SQL Injection.